# trying to get onclick to call a Java script more than once

Tags: javascript, html

First of all my apologies if there is a very obvious answer to this but I have searched extensively to try and find an answer. I am very new to Java script and am really struggling with this problem. I have a form which asks if you stay at another address if you click yes an address block open and you can fill in an other address. under that block you are asked if you want to add a further address if you click yes then I would like another address block to open exactly the same as the first but I get nothing. I am assuming the reason for this is because the JS function has already activated once and will not do so again unless I can give it some means of counting the number of times it has opened or needs to open. I have copied the functioning part of my code below can anyone point out clearly and concisely where I have gone wrong, please bear in mind that my understanding of JS is very limited so an idiot guide would be appreciated.
my code:

```
<div id=content>

<!-- QUESTION TEXT GOES HERE -->

<h3><span class="QID">8</span>Do you stay at another address, other than your current address, for more than 30 days a year?</h3>


<form>
<p></p>
<input type="radio" name="Text">No <a href="PCS_p10.htm">Go to Question 10 </a><br>




<p></br></p>
</form>
<form>
<p></p>
      <script type="text/javascript">


      function checkIt(el) {
        var elArr = ['mtext',];
        for (var i=0; i<elArr.length; i++) {
        sel = document.getElementById(elArr[i]);
        if (el.value == elArr[i]) { sel.style.display = 'block'; }
                               else { sel.style.display = 'none'; }
        }

      }

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="mtext" onclick="checkIt(this)">Yes
     <div id="mtext" style="display:none;width" />
     <input type="text" id="multiple1" size="60" name="text"><br>
     <input type="text" id="multiple2" size="60" name="text"><br>
     <input type="text" id="multiple3" size="60" name="text"><br>
     <input type="text" id="multiple4" size="60" name="text"><br>
     <pre><font face="arial,helvetica" size"+1">                                                         Postcode  <input type="text" id="multiple5" name="postc1" style="width: 40px;" maxlength="4"> <input type="text" name="postc2" style="width: 40px;" maxlength="4"></pre><br>

Add another address  
     <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="mtext" onclick="checkIt(this)">Yes
     <input type="radio" name="Text">No <a href="PCS_p10.htm">Go to Question 10 </a><br>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>

<p></br></p>


</form>
```

Comment: **Java !=javascript**

Comment: `<p>` tags after `</html>`? `</br>`? I am hoping that this is only an error while posting the question.

Comment: The script is running as many times as it is called. It's not opening another block for a new address more than once because you only have the one block to open. As it is, your function won't create a whole new block and put it in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a simple JavaScript code

```
<div id="idofdivblock">
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="mtext" onclick="checkItYes(this)">Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="mtext" onclick="checkItNo(this)">No</input>
</div>
```

**JScript Code**

```
function checkItYes(el) {
document.getElementById("idofdivblock").style.visibility="hidden";
}

function checkItNo(el) {
document.getElementById("idofdivblock").style.visibility="visible";
}
```